# How to rewrite ear application into Spring

Tags: java, spring, ear

I have some ear application which I need to rewrite to spring. War contains one class which run EJB:

```
/**
 * The ear initialization.
 */
public final class Startup extends HttpServlet {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6465240550145652729L;

  @EJB(name="MyStartupBean")
  private MyBeanLocal bean;

  @Override
  public void init(final ServletConfig servletConfiguration) throws ServletException {
    bean.start();
  }


  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    bean.stop();
  }
}
```

EJB contains some quart scheduler which run job every 30s

I really try to find some example of ear spring application with EJB but with no succes. How should I rewrite it into spring ?

Comment: If it is just quartz, why not simply let spring take care of that and remove the EJB all together?

Comment: yea that is one the option. But my boss want as result same ear just with spring. And if it isnt possible I will try to persuade him to create just war

Comment: SO instead of reduced complexity he wants increased complexity... Neat... But see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring supports @EJB (not widely known but it does). So basically you can simply port your class to spring by removing the `extends HttpServlet`, add a `@Component` annotation, simplify the init method and add `@PostConstruct` and add `@PreDestroy`  to the `destroy` method.

```
@Component
public final class Startup {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6465240550145652729L;

  @EJB(name="MyStartupBean")
  private MyBeanLocal bean;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    bean.start();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
    bean.stop();
  }
}
```

Something like that would be the result. Now either declare this bean in xml

```
<bean class="Startup" />
```

Or use component scanning to detect/pickup this bean.

But as mentioned I would probably ditch the EJB altogether and use spring to [bootstrap Quartz](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) instead.